# Creating a div in jquery with multipule html attributes that include variables

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a div in jquery with mulitple attributes that include variables in them. This is what I have so far:

```
var font_text = $('input[name=text_to_add]').val();
var font_color = $('input[name=color_to_add]').val();
$('input[name=add_text]').on('click', function() {
    $('<div class="one_text" data-font-text="'+ font_text + '"  data-font-color= "' + font_color +'" style="left: 75px; top: 50px;"><img src="/files/tmp/' + data.file + '.png"><div class="edit"></div><div class="del"></div></div>').appendTo('#text_content');
});
```

So, data-font-text actually does what needed but data-font-color doesn't. In fact PhpStorm indicates data-font-color, being inclosed in " ", is actually just text. Is it possible to override this problem so that the div data-font-color appears normaly?

This solution works but does not suit my needs, I need different data attributes:

```
$('<div class="one_text" data-font-text="'+ font_text + font_color + '"  style="left: 75px; top: 50px;"><img src="/files/tmp/' + data.file + '.png"><div class="edit"></div><div class="del"></div></div>').appendTo('#text_content');
```

Added the HTML for input[name=color_to_add]

```
<div class="color-box"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="color_to_add" value="#FFFFFF">
```

Comment: Please show us the html for `input[name=color_to_add]`

Comment: how doesn't the `data-font-color` work? try logging the `font_color` using console to see if the value is actually what you want.

Comment: @Murali It's just a text value which gives a HEX. For example #FFFFFF.

Comment: @KingKing When the div is actually appended only 'data-font-text' appears as an attribute. 'data-font-color' doesn't.

Comment: @Murali Added the HTML code.

Comment: @user3541436: its working just fine with your exact code (just changed the img path): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/xMHY4/1/; problem is either with your image file or elsewhere.

Comment: it also works for me here http://jsfiddle.net/EcPex/1/ you can extract the attribute `data-font-color` OK.

Comment: @user3541436: Oh yes.. you need to bring those variable declarations inside the click handler! Otherwise they will always pick the initial value of page load.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different combinations I found that this code is actually correct:

```
 $('<div class="one_text" data-font-text="'+ font_text + '"  data-font-color= "' + font_color +'" style="left: 75px; top: 50px;"><img src="/files/tmp/' + data.file + '.png"><div class="edit"></div><div class="del"></div></div>').appendTo('#text_content');
```

Despite PhpStorm showing data-font-color as text, it is actually working property.

Comment: Wow. Congratulations.